# Google Chrome "Application Shortcut": How to auto-load JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Introduction**
Google chrome has a feature that allows you to create shortcuts to web pages and make them appear like traditional desktop applications.

For example, a shortcut to twitter mobile might be

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --app=https://mobile.twitter.com/
```

The file icon for this app is stored in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\mobile.twitter.com\https_80
```

**My Question**
It's been a while since I've used this feature and I seem to remember that you could add your own JavaScript files to the app folder which were included when the application was loaded. However, I cannot find any documentation that discusses this feature but I'm 99% certain it exists.

Does anyone have any details if this feature is available and what files I need to create?

**Clarification**

I'm basically opening a webpage using Chrome's "Application Shortcut" and I want this webpage to refresh every x seconds. However, I do not have control over this webpage.

I'm sure in older versions of Chrome this used to be possible... unless I'm going mad.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do with your javascript file?   When you say ***included when the application was loading***, what do you exactly mean?   Since I assume you want a link to a website, what is the purpose of the javascript file?

Comment: @GGG I don't see what is the problem of asking that.  There might be other ways to do what he is intending to do.  knowing the ultimate purpose might help people answer in a better way rather than guessing.  Some people might answer like this: *I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after* indicating that they are not sure exactly what the original purpose of the question is.

Comment: @agarcian fair enough. I assumed he wanted full user script capabilities, I didn't even think about cases like this.

Comment: Just for reference I wrote an answer suggesting to set it up as a hosted app and including content scripts, but I just tried it and apparently chrome doesn't allow content scripts in hosted apps, so I'm deleting the answer.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

> Chrome extensions and their content scripts are also loaded when Chrome starts in the App mode.

So, you can create a simple extension, which injects JavaScript code in the page as follows:

#### 1. Create a [`manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) file

```
{
  "name": "Run code on twitter mobile",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "contentscript.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://mobile.twitter.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "script.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://mobile.twitter.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### 2. The content script

Then, create a file called `contentscript.js`, and add the desired JavaScript code.
This script is included at every load of the matched page. All DOM methods, via the `document` object is directly available. However, `window` and `document.defaultView` do **not** point to the `window` object in the page <sup>[[source]](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)</sup>.

If you want to access global methods or properties, you have to dynamically create a `<script>`, and inject it in the page (see [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)).

`contentscript.js`

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};
```

#### 3. The script which will be injected

Then, create a file called `script.js`, and place it in the same folder as `manifest.json` and `contentscript.js`. The code in `script.js` executes as if it was a true part of the affected page.

[Reference for content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/).

[Reference for web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: To load an extension, navigate to `chrome://extensions/`, activate `Developer mode`, and click on the `Load unpacked extension` button. Then, select the directory which contains your `manifest.json` (and `contentscript.js`, `script.js`) file, then confirm. If you want to test the extension in the Private browsing mode, expand the description, and check the box. When you update your script, you **have to** click on `Reload extension`, to see the changes.

Comment: Because all I wanted to do was refresh the page every 30 seconds, all I had to insert into contentscript.js was:

setTimeout(
 "location.reload(true);",
 30 * 1000
);

Comment: @GateKiller You'd better use `setInterval(function(){location.reload(true);}, 30000);` Using a string as an argument for `setTimeout` is discouraged. I replaced `setTimeout` with `setInterval`, to deal with accidental navigation cancelling (which could break your script). If you actually like this feature, use `setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);},3000);`.

Comment: @RobW: What are differences between `window object of page` and `window object of content script`, i have taken a cursory look most of features looked similar barring few page related prototypes, any information on differences?

Comment: @Sudarshan Content scripts run in an own execution context. Most of the DOM methods (eg `appendChild`) are available to both contexts (page and content scripts), but at the same time, they're different. For instance, if you use `document.appendChild = null;` in the page, the content script will still see an unmodified method when it accesses `document.appendChild`. This separation/proxying of context exists for all objects -including `window`- in the page and content script.

Comment: @RobW: Please Correct me if i am wrong, does this mean they make a copy of original page window and give it to content script `document.defaultview` ?

Comment: @Sudarshan It's not copied (that'd be expensive), but accessed via a proxy. To get it clear, the `window`, `parent`, `top`, `frames`, `document.defaultView`, etc. all refer to the global object in a content script, which is completely different from the page's one.

Comment: @RobW: Absolutely stellar tutorials - thanks!  But the Chrome documentation indicates that content scripts must have both "tab" and "host" permissions in order to inject code.  You may wish to include a permissions section in your `manifest.json` file.

Comment: @Dave The `tabs` permission is [only needed under a few circumstances](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#manifest), programmatic script execution is not one of them. Further, the host permissions are not needed, because they are implied by the `"matches"` key of the content script declaration in the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks - the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi could be clearer on that point, both by mentioning that host permissions are NOT needed, and that `web_accessible_resources:` IS.

Comment: Is there any way to send message back to the background script using the second (2. The content script) option?

Comment: I got an error using this because the format for "web_accessible_resources" changed, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/ .  One should do something like: ```"web_accessible_resources": [  {"matches": ["http://mobile.twitter.com/*"],    "resources":["script.js"]    }  ]```

Comment: s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js'); //deprecated

should be replaced with

s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('script.js');

Answer (score -5):

I assume you want to include a javascript to do some 'launching' of the application, perhaps to resize the window when loading your target url?

Here is something you could do, as suggested in [this post](http://www.eddieoneverything.com/articles/how-to-set-the-window-size-and-position-of-a-chrome-application-shortcut.php)

Create an Html page locally that contains the javascript that you need to run.

Change this:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --app=https://mobile.twitter.com/`

to this:

`C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe”  –app=file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/<username>/My%20Documents/My
%20Custom%20Shortcuts/twitter_mobile_launcher.html`

and your **twitter_mobile_launcher.html** file would look like this:

```
<html>  
 <head>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
   // Do what you need with your javascript, for example, resizing your window...
   window.resizeTo(300,400);  
   window.moveTo(300,0);  
   window.location = "https://mobile.twitter.com/";  
  </script>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
  <h1>If you see this, the redirect did not work properly.</h1>  
 </body>  
</html>
```