# Chrome V71 breaks Extension JS injection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using Method 1 described here

[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

which is based on

[Google Chrome "Application Shortcut": How to auto-load JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263671/google-chrome-application-shortcut-how-to-auto-load-javascript/9310273#9310273)

This was working fine but after my browser (Chrome) updated to v71 this does not work anymore as my elements can't find the functions in my injected JS file anymore. I prepared an easy example:

**manifest.json**

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
     "web_accessible_resources": 
                [
                    "Callbacks.js"
                ],  
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://stackoverflow.com/"], 
        "js": ["inject.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**inject.js**

```
function newButton(id, cb) 
{
    var b = document.createElement("div");
    b.setAttribute("onclick",cb);
    b.style.margin = "50px"
    b.style.width = "100px";
    b.style.height = "100px";   
    b.style.background = "gray";
    b.style.zIndex = 10000000;
    b.style.position = "absolute";
    b.id = id;  
    return b;
}

    var cc= document.createElement("script");
    cc.src =  chrome.runtime.getURL('Callbacks.js') ;
    document.body.appendChild(cc);

    document.body.appendChild(newButton("myId", "myfun();"));
```

**Callbacks.js**

```
function myfun(){
    window.alert("hallo");
}
```

When going on stackoverflow.com and clicking on the gray div I see this in my console

*(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myfun is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):1)
onclick @ (index):1*

However, I can still call myfun from the console directly.

Any ideas about this? With older Chrome version this still works.

Comment: https://crbug.com/912069

Comment: Until this is fixed you'll have to create the element inside your page-level script (Callbacks.js).

Comment: In my actual application I make API calls like chrome.runtime.getURL which will not work on the page level, right? I would need to somehow transfer these variables (results from the call to the API functions) from the content script into the page level script. Any good idea for that?

Comment: You can use [custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26740141/934239) for communication. (there's a chain of linked questions with more details / solutions)

Comment: You can put the code into a string and modify it to pass the variables via JSON.stringify, then get them via JSON.parse inside. The string should be assigned to scriptElement.textContent, of course.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for all the input. With the changes, my actual extension is working fine again. When you leave a post I can mark this thread as answered

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restructured as mentioned by @wOxxOm which works fine now.